# Error : "Log cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I imported a project from a war in my eclipse which is working fine when it was exported. But in my PC it's not working and throwing errors as "Log cannot be resolved to a type". I already have the required jars in WEB-INF\lib folder. Stacktrace is as follows:

```
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'spring'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'spring': initialization started
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'spring-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 30 12:37:05 IST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport loadProperties
INFO: Loading properties file from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties]
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@f75c33: defining beans [projectController,projectDaoImpl,subtrackDaoImpl,trackDaoImpl,projectServiceImpl,subtrackServiceImpl,trackServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,tilesViewResolver,tilesConfigurer,messageSource,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.mvc.project.bean.Subtrack
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity com.mvc.project.bean.Subtrack on table Subtrack
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder bindClass
INFO: Binding entity from annotated class: com.mvc.project.bean.Project
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.EntityBinder bindTable
INFO: Bind entity com.mvc.project.bean.Project on table Project
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder bindOneToManySecondPass
INFO: Mapping collection: com.mvc.project.bean.Subtrack.project -> Project
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
INFO: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean buildSessionFactory
INFO: Building new Hibernate SessionFactory
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/index/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/home] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/home.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/home/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/nextPage] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/nextPage.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/nextPage/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/tab2] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/tab2.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/tab2/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/tab] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/tab.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/tab/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/addproj] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/addproj.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/addproj/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Edit] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Edit.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Edit/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/Addproject.do] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/report] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/report.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/report/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/exporttoexcel] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/exporttoexcel.*] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/exporttoexcel/] onto handler 'projectController'
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer setDefinitions
INFO: TilesConfigurer: adding definitions [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@f75c33: defining beans [projectController,projectDaoImpl,subtrackDaoImpl,trackDaoImpl,projectServiceImpl,subtrackServiceImpl,trackServiceImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,tilesViewResolver,tilesConfigurer,messageSource,propertyConfigurer,dataSource,sessionFactory,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,transactionManager]; root of factory hierarchy
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean destroy
INFO: Closing Hibernate SessionFactory
Jul 30, 2014 12:37:05 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tilesConfigurer' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache.commons.logging cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.commons.logging cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    LogFactory cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    LogFactory cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1008)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The import org.apache.commons.logging cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache.commons.logging cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    LogFactory cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    LogFactory cannot be resolved
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type
    Log cannot be resolved to a type

    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.<init>(Digester.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.definition.digester.DigesterDefinitionsReader.<init>(DigesterDefinitionsReader.java:274)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsReader(TilesConfigurer.java:450)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createLocaleDefinitionDao(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:297)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer$SpringTilesContainerFactory.createDefinitionsFactory(TilesConfigurer.java:481)
    at org.apache.tiles.factory.BasicTilesContainerFactory.createContainer(BasicTilesContainerFactory.java:104)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainer(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.initialize(AbstractTilesInitializer.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer.afterPropertiesSet(TilesConfigurer.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 32 more
```

here are all the jars in my lib folder.

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar
aopalliance-1.0-sources.jar
aopalliance-1.0.jar
asm-3.2-sources.jar
asm-3.3.1.jar
asm-attrs.jar
cglib-2.2.2-sources.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.0.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar
commons-dbcp-1.2.2.jar
commons-digester-2.0-sources.jar
commons-digester-2.0.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.3.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
groovy-all-2.0.1.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.3.1.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
hibernate-core-3.3.2.GA.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.3.2.GA.jar
hibernate3.3.2.jar
itext-2.1.7.jar
jackson-core-2.1.4.jar
jackson-core-asl-1.9.7.jar
jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.9.jar
jasperreports-5.5.2.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
javax.persistence.jar
javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar
jfreechart-1.0.13.jar
jsp-api.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
jta-1.1.jar
junit-3.8.1.jar
list.txt
log4j-1.2.15.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.21.jar
org.apache.commons.beanutils.jar
poi-3.9.jar
slf4j-api-1.5.0.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.0.jar
spring-aop-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar
tiles-api-2.2.1.jar
tiles-core-2.2.1.jar
tiles-jsp-2.2.1.jar
tiles-servlet-2.2.1.jar
tiles-template-2.2.1.jar
```

Comment: Have you add 
slf4j-api-xxx.jar and slf4j-simple-xxx.jar

Comment: my friend told me that the project was on maven initially, but she changed it to non maven by using eclipse. Can this create any problem?

Comment: Did you clean and  build project again? you can see these compilation error in editor.

Comment: yes I did by using Project> clean> clean all project, but the problem persist.

Comment: solved it: 
While importing the war eclipse created another projects with the names of jar which are present in lib folder. Some of those project were showing red marks that is there was some problem with them. I deleted all those project and rerun the project. Now it said that it can't find the following exception class: 

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException

I downloaded the jasper reports jar again and put it in the lib folder and voila!! 

the project is up. 

Thanks guys for helping me specially Neeraj. Not enough repo to vote up or answer my own question though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it: While importing the war eclipse created another projects with the names of jar which are present in lib folder. Some of those project were showing red marks that is there was some problem with them. I deleted all those project and rerun the project. Now it said that it can't find the following exception class: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException I downloaded the jasper reports jar again and put it in the lib folder and voila!! the project is up. Thanks guys for helping me specially Neeraj.